# Chess.js swap turns

Tags: javascript, chess

I've looked at [this thread](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/issues/62) and asked the question there as well, but there hasn't been a response in 2 years.

Does anyone know how I am able to change the turn using the chess.js library? I followed the project dev's suggestion of swapping out the turn in the FEN (from the linked thread), but that results in an invalid FEN and every move after it fails. I went in and commented out the FEN validation in the library, and it mostly works. However, the simple moves `d4 skip` breaks everything. After this, the library thinks white has these moves:

```js
(20) […]
0: Object { color: "w", from: "d4", to: "d5", … }
1: Object { color: "w", from: "a2", to: "a3", … }
2: Object { color: "w", from: "a2", to: "a4", … }
3: Object { color: "w", from: "b2", to: "b3", … }
4: Object { color: "w", from: "b2", to: "b4", … }
5: Object { color: "w", from: "c2", to: "c3", … }
6: Object { color: "w", from: "c2", to: "c4", … }
7: Object { color: "w", from: "c2", to: "d3", … }
8: Object { color: "w", from: "e2", to: "d3", … }
9: Object { color: "w", from: "b1", to: "d2", … }
10: Object { color: "w", from: "c1", to: "d2", … }
11: Object { color: "w", from: "c1", to: "e3", … }
12: Object { color: "w", from: "c1", to: "f4", … }
13: Object { color: "w", from: "c1", to: "g5", … }
14: Object { color: "w", from: "c1", to: "h6", … }
15: Object { color: "w", from: "d1", to: "d2", … }
16: Object { color: "w", from: "d1", to: "d3", … }
17: Object { color: "w", from: "e1", to: "d2", … }
18: Object { color: "w", from: "g1", to: "f3", … }
19: Object { color: "w", from: "g1", to: "h3", … }
length: 20
```

Some things to note:

- It allows exd3 and cxd3
- It disallows e3 and e4
- It disallows bNa3 and bNc3

These things tell me that the game thinks the white king is in check from d3, but at the same time it still allows for c3 and c4. I'm really banging my head against this problem.

Does anyone know a better way to skip the turn using chess.js instead of swapping the turn in the FEN and disabling the FEN validation?

Comment: I didn't know skipping was a valid move in chess...

Comment: Why do you expect the library to support something that isn't possible in chess? You can't just say "meh, I'm in zugzwang, I'm going to pass my turn" The best thing I can think of is to make a bunch of reversible moves for both players so that the result is the turn being swapped but the board remains the same.

Comment: For example, after `1. e4 e5`, if you wanted it to be Black's turn, you could do `2. Qe2 Qg5 3. Qf3 Qd8 4. Qd1`, and now you're in the same position but it's Black's turn. IDK how you'd programatically do this though.

Comment: I want to skip the turn because I'm making a chess game with a modified ruleset. Obviously it's not a normal valid move, but the library also supports arbitrarily adding and removing pieces from the board which isn't valid either. Saying "well it's not valid" is not useful in any way to me. Making reversible moves in this board state is unfortunately not possible, because this board state is not "normally" reachable to begin with. That is why I had to uncomment the FEN validation.

Comment: Can you share the FEN that failed validation? AFAIK, simply changing the turn flag in the FEN (the b/w character in the second field) shouldn't break anything as long as you take care of the en-passant flag and set it to `-`

Comment: I think you've pointed me in the right direction! I was making a mistake by not changing the en passant flag, and incorrectly mistook it as the FEN validation *failing* because someone else in the Github issue said they experienced the same thing. I would accept this as the correct answer.